# How do you use a form to edit several records that consist of a pair of fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Forgive me if the question seems vague and confusing, I'm not too sure how to describe what I'm specifically trying to do without explaining with code.

I got a Model with two fields, 'data' and 'value', and (currently) I have 4 records in it:

```
#Configuration

data: 'text1', value: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
data: 'text2', value: 'Integer rutrum dolor eget varius tincidunt'
data: 'image1', value: 'small_logo1.png'
data: 'image2', value: 'big_logo1.png'
```

In case you're wondering they're meant to contain 'settings' values. I do not know how many of these I'm going to use, which is why I'm using the 'data' and 'value' pairs.

I'd like to edit these 4 records in a single form, but I'm not sure how to limit my `form_for` or `fields_for` so that it edits these 4 particular values separately.

If I use `form_for`, I need to either specify a new "Configuration" or pick an existing one. If I use a `fields_for` loop, I guess I could go through all the records, however some of them will have different formats, such as a file upload, or a textarea, which would mean I'd have to do many if-then-else conditions.

Is there a way to grab these 4 records, and contain them all in the same form? "horizontally" rather than "vertically".

Sounds kinda simple (I think), I just don't know what to google exactly. :|

EDIT: Guess my question is too confusing. Ideally I'd want to end with something like this:

```
<textarea name="configuration[text1][value]"></textarea>
<textarea name="configuration[text2][value]"></textarea>
<input name="configuration[image1][value]"></input>
<input name="configuration[image2][value]"></input>
```

I tried this in my view:

```
=form_for :configuration do |f|
  f.text_area '[text1][value]'
  f.text_area '[text1][value]'
  f.text_field '[image1][value]'
  f.text_field '[image1][value]'
```

But that outputs the names like "configuration[[text1][value]]", which is understandable.